# Extending the extension manager

Tags: visual-studio-2010, extensibility, vsix

I want to extend the extension manager in Visual Studio 2010. I'd rather know if that is at all possible before I get into it, but am unable to find anything about it.

All the extensibility options I've read about mention nothing about being able to actually change the function of an existing VS2010 tool like the extension manager.

I'd appreciate any relevant links.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no supported interfaces for extending the Extension Manager in Visual Studio 2010.

What specifically did you have in mind though? Perhaps there's some other way you can accomplish what you're trying to do...

Comment: I can probably accomplish what I want by adding a new extension manager. My idea was mostly about showing more info about each extension in the manager itself and adding extra extension "repositories", as it were.